# Can I access both MySQL and MongoDB with JPA?

Tags: mongodb, jpa

My scenario is that I have some payment transaction data in MySQL and some documents like invoices documents in MongoDB. There are no association need between these two data store. The question is how I can access both of them at the same time with O/R Mapping support. It seems we can have JPA for MongoDB. But I'm not sure how we can access both data store with the JPA api in the same application.

Thanks!

Comment: For simplicity, I switched to use http://vznet.github.com/mongo-jackson-mapper/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseLink (as of 2.4) has JPA support for both MySQL and MongoDB.  EclipseLink also supports Composite Persistence UNits, that allows multiple persistence units to be accessed as a single persistence unit, and allows relationships across them.

Comment: The relationship across multiple persistence unit seems very attractive. Is there a sample for this purpose?

Comment: It seems that we need to wait until next release of EclipseLink. The current version is 2.3.2, and mongodb is only available in 2.4 according to document:  "As of EclipseLink 2.4, EclipseLink has added JPA support for NoSQL databases, initially with support for MongoDB and Oracle NoSQL."

Answer (score 1):

In general JPA does not limit number of persistence units. I haven't used multiple persistence units with MongoDB though, but there should be nothing special.

You can have one persistence unit, which have MySQL data source, and other one with MongoDB as data source. Then you just go and use @PersistenceContext with unitName and inject EntityManager that operates to correct data source.