# Transaction atomicity with MySQL, MongoDB, RabbitMQ

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, transactions, rabbitmq

I have a Java project with these 3 datasources: MySQL, MongoDB, RabbitMQ.
I'm trying to find a way to execute "transactions" (because MongoDB isn't, in fact, transactional) on all 3 datasources as a single transaction, so that if one of them fails, the others will do a rollback.

Problem is, I couldn't find such a solution: JTA implentation (Atomikos etc.) don't support MongoDB.
Also, I saw a suggestion ([Can I access both MySQL and MongoDB with JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857111/can-i-access-both-mysql-and-mongodb-with-jpa)) to use EclipseLink, but to my understanding it doesn't support RabbitMQ.

Is there something I'm missing? Maybe there's a way to extend an existing solution? Or some other way to achieve atomicity?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Note that even MySQL is only transactional when using InnoDB. If you are using MyISAM, it will silently ignore your attempts to use transactions

Comment: I'm using InnoDB in MySQL.

Comment: I think you might be looking at this wrong, if you are attempt to achieve true atomicity across all those techs at the same time then you might as well not be using the other two. THe whole point here is that you need to embrace eventual consistentcy

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear enough that "transaction" part isn't very important, I just want to find a way to make sure that either all 3 datasources fail or they all succeed, so they're consistent with each other.

Comment: I think what you should do is not care and when the result consumption is commited from the other 2 data sources check that they exist in the primary dfatasource, i.e. MySQL and if the do carry on otherwise remove it. That is how these things are best done

Comment: To add to @Sammaye's solution, it would be far easier to debug/trace that way.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand this solutions:
@Sammaye and zaq178miami are basically talking about the same thing, where I should implement a sort of "3 phase commit" myself, right?

Comment: No zaq178miami is...well tbh I dunno what he is on about and how he thinks that will work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [two-phase commit protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol) is what you need.

Comment: Yeah, but I couldn't find an existing solution that supports all 3 mentioned datasources. Or did you mean I should implement it myself?

Comment: It's a quite specific task to your application architecture and technologies you use. I don't think someone already implemented stuff like you want. So, yes, you'll have to implement it yourself. In fact, mongodb has a good manual on how to implement that http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/, I can also suggest to acquire a AMQP message, then in consumer start mysql transaction, do some mongodb related work, verify that all things done and commit + acknowledge message (or cleanup, rollback and reject), but it even sounds quite unstable.